# Numbers create a chart with transposed data

Tags: numbers

I'm willing to use numbers to create a chart.

Unfortunately it is creating the chart using the rows of my data source and I can find how to tell it to use columns instead.

Do you know how I could set that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it out. It was actually simple. I just had to go to the table containing the data and click on the little icon at the top-left of the table.

I added a couple of pictures to clarify what I had to click.
Notice the arrow on the first arrow that shows the button you have to click.

[image: Graph by columns][image: Graph by rows]

Comment: This is exactly what it says in the Help documentation. I just don't have any option like that. Can you at please give the name of the menu item or the action that must be performed? Right now I'm right-clicking (control-clicking) on the the little spotted box that appears in the very upper left corner and I just don't see any such options! If I don't look at the contextual menu that comes up, all I can do is scale and move the table, without or with the icon visible.

Comment: I added a couple of picture. I hope it is clearer now.